# Data will not refresh after AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a HTML table with three columns

```
ID, BuildingLocation, Status
```

and a `Active Link` in each row. When I Click on Active Link, Status value changed from 0 to 1 into the database but updated value data from the database is not displayed into the HTML table. It will display when I press the F5 key.

**Building.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function Active(ID) 
{   
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "buildingactive.php",
        data: {ID:ID},

        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) 
        {
            $("#Response").html(data);
        },
        error: function(err) 
        {
            //console.log("Fail"+err.call);
            $("#Response").html(err);
        }
    });

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $sq="Select * from buildingmaster";

    $Table=mysqli_query($CN,$sq);

    while ($Row=mysqli_fetch_array($Table))
    {  
        $ID=$Row['ID'];

        echo("<tr>");
        echo("<td>".$Row["ID"]."</td>");
        echo("<td>".$Row["BuildingLocation"]."</td>");
        echo("<td>".$Row["Status"]."</td>");

        echo("<td>");
        echo("<a href='#' onclick='Active($ID)'>Change</a>");
        echo("</td>");
        echo("</tr>");  
    }
    ?>
</table>
    <?php                                   
        echo("<div>");
        echo("<p id='Response'></p>");
echo("</div>"); 
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

buildingactive.php

This is my PHP file which is used to update the status column of the buildingmaster table.

```
<?php
$ID=$_POST['ID'];
$UpdateQuery="Update  buildingmaster set Status=1 where ID=$ID";

require_once "connection.php";
$R=mysqli_query($CN,$UpdateQuery);

if($R==1)
{   
$res="Building Active Successfully:";
echo json_encode($res);
}
else 
{
$error="Server Error... Try Again...";
echo json_encode($error);
}

?>
```

Comment: in your code you are not updating value in your html table, when request success OR fail. so how you can expect a new value on your screen. even your `buildingactive.php` just returning success/fail message. you should return new value from this php page, and that value you should display in html table's td. the same way you are showing message in `#Response` element

Comment: even from `select` and `update` query it looks you have 2 different columns `StatusName` and `Status`.  as in select you are using `StatusName` and in update you are using `Status`

Comment: ok while your issue just in returned data from php file and while you just trying to return plain text so no need to use `dataType: "JSON",` and in php just echo out the plain text with `echo($res)` and `echo($error)`

Comment: ya it was my typing mistake. the Column name is Status

Comment: How I return updated value and display it in HTML Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass status value along with success message like,

```
$res={status:'1', msg: 'Building Active Successfully:'};
```

And you have to decode the data in Ajax success

```
var myObj = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Modified Code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function Active(ID) 
{   
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "buildingactive.php",
        data: {ID:ID},

        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) 
        {
            $("#Response").html(data.msg);
            $(".row"+ID).text(data.staus);
            $("#Response").addClass("alert alert-success");
            $("#Response").fadeOut(3000);

        },
        error: function(err) 
        {
            //console.log("Fail"+err.call);
            $("#Response").html(err);
            $("#Response").addClass("alert alert-danger");
            $("#Response").fadeOut(3000);
        }
    });

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $sq="Select * from buildingmaster";

    $Table=mysqli_query($CN,$sq);

    while ($Row=mysqli_fetch_array($Table))
    {  
        $ID=$Row['ID'];

        echo("<tr>");
        echo("<td class='row".$ID."'>".$Row["ID"]."</td>");
        echo("<td>".$Row["BuildingLocation"]."</td>");
        echo("<td>".$Row["StatusName"]."</td>");

        echo("<td>");
        echo("<a href='#' onclick='Active($ID)'>Change</i></a>");
        echo("</td>");
        echo("</tr>");  
    }
    ?>
</table>
    <?php                                   
        echo("<div>");
        echo("<p id='Response'></p>");
echo("</div>"); 
    ?>
</body>
</html>


<?php
$ID=$_POST['ID'];
$UpdateQuery="Update  buildingmaster set Status=1 where ID=$ID";

require_once "connection.php";
$R=mysqli_query($CN,$UpdateQuery);

if($R==1)
{   
$res={status:'1', msg: 'Building Active Successfully:'};
echo json_encode($res);
}
else 
{
$error="Server Error... Try Again...";
echo json_encode($error);
}

?>
```

Comment: Thankx for your valuable & simple Answer

Answer (score 0):

Add to `success: function(data){}`

either `window.location.reload();` or you can
assign

`window.location = window.location`